# Drupal dynamic google maps

Tags: drupal

i am using drupal 6.2 version. In my contact form i want to display all my branches which has to be manage my adminstrator. According to that branches address how i can display the google map dynamically. I tried with gmap module. but it was showing one address. Kindly provide me in steps to acheive this..

Answer (score 0):

With Views and GMap modules you can create a View which will display each of your branches as a marker on a Google map,